# In PowerShell, how can I determine if the current drive is a networked drive or not?

Tags: c#, powershell, networking, mapped-drive

I need to know, from within Powershell, if the current drive is a mapped drive or not.

Unfortunately, Get-PSDrive is not working "as expected":

```
PS:24 H:\temp
>get-psdrive  h

Name       Provider      Root      CurrentLocation
----       --------      ----      ---------------
H          FileSystem    H:\          temp
```

but in MS-Dos "net use" shows that H: is really a mapped network drive:

```
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           H:        \\spma1fp1\JARAVJ$        Microsoft Windows Network

The command completed successfully.
```

What I want to do is to get the root of the drive and show it in the prompt (see: [Customizing PowerShell Prompt - Equivalent to CMD's $M$P$_$+$G?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157923/customizing-powershell-prompt-equivalent-to-cmds-mpg))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the .NET framework:

```
PS H:\> $x = new-object system.io.driveinfo("h:\")
PS H:\> $x.drivetype
Network
```

Comment: Good tip!

And then how do I get the Rootdirectory=

Unfortunately RootDirectory points to H:\ again...

Comment: @jjarava -- I belatedly realized that although the DriveInfo class will tell you the drive type it won't return the network path.  Perhaps one of the other answers can provide that.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more compact variation on the accepted answer:

```
[System.IO.DriveInfo]("C")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try WMI:

```
Get-WMI -query "Select ProviderName From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DeviceID='H:'"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to use WMI:

`get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk | ? {$_.deviceid -eq "s:"} | % {$_.providername}`

Get all network drives with:

`get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk | ? {$_.drivetype -eq 4} | % {$_.providername}`

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way is to use WMI

```
get-wmiobject win32_volume | ? { $_.DriveType -eq 4 } | % { get-psdrive $_.DriveLetter[0] }
```

The DriveType is an enum wit hthe following values

0 - Unknown 
1 - No Root Directory 
2 - Removable Disk 
3 - Local Disk 
4 - Network Drive 
5 - Compact Disk 
6 - RAM Disk

Here's a link to a blog post I did [on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2007/12/06/filtering-get-psdrive-to-all-local-drives.aspx)

Comment: The only "gotcha" with this approach (that seems much cleaner) is that  I'm running WINXP, so the win32_volume class is not available!

Thanks for the tip anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Take this a step further as shown below:

```
([System.IO.DriveInfo]("C")).Drivetype
```

Note this only works for the the local system.  Use WMI for remote computers.