# How to check drive format type with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a few codes here that work but I need something new.
I have drive letter detect and if CD Exist in drive batch code

But now I need if is a cd drive batch code and if not do other thing

Codes I Have:

if CD in drive:

```
@echo off
title CD Test

:main
CLS
WMIC CDROM E: GET MEDIALOADED | FINDSTR "TRUE"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
goto one
) ELSE (
goto two
)
```

If Drive Letter Exist:

```
@echo off
title If Exist Test

:main
CLS
echo.
echo press any key to see if drive C:\ exists
echo.
pause>nul
IF EXIST C:\ (GOTO yes) ELSE (GOTO no)
```

There and while both of those are working great I have no idea how to tell if its a cd drive or say NTFS or FAT32  I believe CD drive format if CDFS but im not sure.

So i need a code that will tell me if drive is NTFS/FAT32 or CDFS and goto 1 option or other based on findings.

Or would it be better to just check if drive letter is empty? 0 bytes...
Would that effect if say a empty usb was plugged in it could be called a cd drive?

Comment: Use .net commands  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158359/in-powershell-how-can-i-determine-if-the-current-drive-is-a-networked-drive-or

Comment: `wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,filesystem`

Comment: Can I get a full @echo off code please, not just suggestions, Thanks    I need to get this working, While the: wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,filesystem does tell what drive is, it doest help me in my batch code that much.

Comment: `wmic logicaldisk where caption="E:" get description|find "CD">nul && echo it's a CD-Drive || echo It's not`. I'm sure, you're able to add the `@echo off` yourself.

Comment: got it to work, and changed it to goto yes || goto nope ... but you got it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
title If CD Test

:main
CLS
wmic logicaldisk where caption="E:" get description|find "CD">nul && echo it's a CD-Drive    || echo It's not
pause
```

There ya go, im sure u just didnt understand how it was formatted in comments 
It looks better as code in an answer.

Comment: Thanks that exactly what im looking for i just changed the... echo it's a CD with... goto yes || goto nope... other then that exactly what i wanted thanks.