# In PowerShell, how can I determine the root of a drive (supposing it's a networked drive)

Tags: powershell, networking, mapped-drive

In PowerShell, even if it's possible to know if a drive is a network drive: see [In PowerShell, how can I determine if the current drive is a networked drive or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158359/in-powershell-how-can-i-determine-if-the-current-drive-is-a-networked-drive-or)

When I try to get the "root" of the drive, I get back the drive letter.

The setup:
MS-Dos "net use" shows that H: is really a mapped network drive:

```
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           H:        \\spma1fp1\JARAVJ$        Microsoft Windows Network

The command completed successfully.
```

Get-PSDrive tells us that the Root is H:

```
PS:24 H:\temp
>get-psdrive  h

Name       Provider      Root      CurrentLocation
----       --------      ----      ---------------
H          FileSystem    H:\          temp
```

and using system.io.driveinfo does not give us a complete answer:

```
PS:13 H:\
>$x = new-object system.io.driveinfo("h:\")
PS:14 H:\
>$x.DriveType
Network
PS:15 H:\
>$x.RootDirectory

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        29/09/2008     16:45            h:\
```

Any idea of how to get that info?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try WMI:

```
Get-WMIObject -query "Select ProviderName From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DeviceID='H:'"
```

Comment: A minor nit, it's Get-WMIObject instead of Get-WMI :)

Comment: yup. I'll edit. I actually used the gwmi alias then meant to de-alias it for posting and was only partially successful.

Answer (score 6):

The trick is that the attribute name is different than expected.
Try:

`(Get-PSDrive h).DisplayRoot`

Answer (score 0):

$drive = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "DeviceID='H:'"
if($drive.DriveType -eq 4) {write-host "drive is a network share"}

Answer (score 0):

$fso=new-object -com "Scripting.Filesystemobject"
$fso.GetDrive("Y").ShareName